# Android Studio async downloading file from FireBase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-storage

I want to download 4 pictures from FireBase Storage and load them in 4 ImageButton in my Activity.

I can download the file in my internal storage but i can't set the pictures in ImageButton conteined in my activity, because i recive the error
"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4"

I think the problem is the async download from FireBase inside a for loop. Maybe in the first cicle of loop, it requests the first file, but while the first file is being download the for loop doesn't wait it and keep incrementing index i. When the file has been dowloaded the index i is "OutOfBounds".

Do you think this is the problem?

**How can i solve it?**
Thanyou in advance.

The error is:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.grigliaconscelta, PID: 27029
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //NUMBER OF PICTURES I WANT TO DOWNLOAD
    int num_modelli = 4;
    //ARRAY WHERE I'LL STORE THE FILES DOWNLOADED
    File[] mypath = new File[num_modelli];
    int i = 0;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    //FOLDER THAT CONTAINS IMAGE IN FIREBASE
    StorageReference folder = storage.getReference().child("test");
    //WILL CONTAIN THE INFO ABOUT "TEST" FOLDER IN FIREBASE STORAGE
    ListResult listResult;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String nomeFile;

    //THE ACTIVITY COMPONENT THAT WILL CONTAINS THE PICTURES DOWNLOADED FROM FIREBASE
    ImageButton[] myImageButton = new ImageButton[num_modelli];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // BINDING OF THE IMAGEBUTTON COMPONENT WITH THE ELEMENT OF ARRAY
        myImageButton[0] = findViewById(R.id.imageButton0);
        myImageButton[1] = findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        myImageButton[2] = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        myImageButton[3] = findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);


        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);


        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        // SET THE DIRECTORY USED TO STORE THE FILE IN INTERNAL STORAGE
        final File directory = cw.getDir("imageGrid", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        //GET INFORMATION FROM THE "TEST" FOLDER IN FIREBASE STORAGE
        folder.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                System.out.println("NUMBER OF FILES : " + listResult.getItems().size());

                //LOOP FOR DOWNLOAD EVERY FILE IN THE "TEST" FOLDER AND SET IT IN THE CORRESPONDENT IMAGEBUTTON IN ACTIVITY
                for (i = 0; i < num_modelli; i++) {
                    //READ THE NAME OF FIRST FILE IN TEST FOLDER
                    nomeFile = listResult.getItems().get(i).getName();
                    //CREATE THE FILE IN THE INTERNAL STORAGE OF DEVICE
                    mypath[i] = new File(directory, nomeFile);
                    //POINT AT THE FILE TO DOWNLOAD
                    folder = storage.getReference().child("test/" + nomeFile);
                    //System.out.println("FOLDER PATH " + folder.getPath());

                    //DOWNLOAD THE FILE POINTED TO FOLDER IN THE FILE INSIDE THE DEVICE REFERENCED IN MYPATH[I]
                    folder.getFile(mypath[i]).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            System.out.println("FILE CREATED " + directory.getPath());
                            //DECONDE THE FILE DOWNLOADED AND STORED IN DEVICE
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(directory + "/" +mypath[i].getName());
                            //SET THE IMAGE IN THE COMPONENT OF ACTIVITY
                            myImageButton[i].setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            //REFRESH THE COMPONENT
                            myImageButton[i].refreshDrawableState();

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("FILE NOT CREATED " + e.toString());

                        }
                    });
                }


            }


        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to download 4 pictures from FireBase Storage and load them in 4 ImageButton in my Activity.

I think that you'll find [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library very usfull.
you'll need to get from each storageReference its download url, and you'll be all set.

heres one way to do it (BTW I personaly think you need to hold your ImageButtons seperetly and not inside an array, but I'm not familiar entirely with what you'r looking to accomplish):

```
folder.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            //iterating through all listed results to get their storageReference
            for(StorageReference storageReference: listResult.getItems()){
                //asynchronously you'll get the urls from all of listed storageReferences
                storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        //now we have the url (uri.toString()) and we can use picasso to display it
                        //i would HIGHLY recommend you to check its caching capabilities to prevent downloading from the storage more than once. 
                        //(unless the pictures are bound to change constantly
                        Picasso.get().load(uri.toString()).placeholder([drawable to display untill image is loaded]).into(myImageButton[i], new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                //handle successes 
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError(Exception e) {
                                //laoding url to view failed
                                //your way of handling it....
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //getting download url failed
                        //your way of handling it....
                    }
                });
                //dont forget to increment i for the next async task
                i++;
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            //getting storageReferences failed
            //your way of handling it....
        }
    });
```

good luck!